# Lambda access to Kibana service on EC2 instance and also to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

An Elastic IP was assigned to EC2, and an ELK service was built in the EC2 instance. In the security group, we restricted the Kibana service on port 9000, and only allowed private addresses (VPC) in AWS VPC to access the Kibana service.

Now I need the Lambda function to access port 9000 through the EC2 private address, and the Lambda function can also access the contents of an S3 bucket when accessing through the EC2 private IP address.

How can I set this up?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Lambda function will need to be **connected to the VPC**. This will give it an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) with a private IP address.

To configure the **security**:

- Create a **Security Group for the Lambda function** (`Lambda-SG`). Leave with default settings (Allow all outbound).
- On the **Security Group for the Kibana server**, allow inbound connections on port 9000 from `Lambda-SG` (refer to it by name, then selecting it will insert the ID of the Lambda security group).

To allow the Lambda function to also **access Amazon S3**, choose one of the following:

- Add a **NAT Gateway** to a public subnet and configure the Route Table of the private subnet (used by Lambda) to send `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to the NAT Gateway. *OR*
- Add a **VPC Endpoint for S3** to the VPC. This will route requests directly to S3 instead of going via the Internet Gateway.

Comment: I have solved this problem according to your method, thank you very much for your help!